# losetup: bootable.iso: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, iso-image

I have a custom-made ISO image with one partition of type FAT16 (it's effectively blank) and am trying to run `losetup` on it**, but the command continues to report that the ISO does not exist. Here is the command that I'm trying to run and resulting output:

```
losetup -o $START --sizelimit $SIZE --show --find bootable.iso
...
losetup: bootable.iso: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory
```

What might be the issue here?

The variable `START` is equal to `512 * 2048` and `SIZE` is equal to `"99M"`.

My base OS is Centos7.

**I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@agustin_29997/how-to-generate-a-bootable-iso-from-a-docker-image-1a323e5a0f43) to create a bootable ISO from a custom docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was quite simple, it turns out: I needed to run with `sudo`. I discovered this by running the command with `strace` and seeing that other files were being reported as non-existent, some of which are only available to root:

```
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/loop-control", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
stat("/dev/loop", 0x7ffe4de4e210)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/dev/loop0", 0x7ffe4de4d170)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/sys/block/loop0/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/home/vagrant/f-16_space", 4095) = 25
readlink("/home/vagrant/f-16_space/bootable.iso", 0x7ffe4de4c270, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
open("/home/vagrant/f-16_space/bootable.iso", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/loop0", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "losetup: ", 9losetup: )                = 9
write(2, "bootable.iso: failed to set up l"..., 42bootable.iso: failed to set up loop device) = 42
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "No such file or directory\n", 26No such file or directory
) = 26
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: In old Linux systems, loop0..loop7 used to be pre-created. In modern systems, losetup has to explicitly create them via loop-control; if it cannot access loop-control, it falls back to the old method of looking for an existing loop0, and fails to report the original error it received when accessing loop-control.

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for that explanation.